# Want to delete all commits from a branch in git

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have messed up my branch and I want to delete all commits from it now, without deleting the branch itself. Is there any way in git we can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways but the easiest is to reset it to a state you like, in this case it sounds like you want to reset it to be exactly like master.

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will force the branch pointer to point to the same commit as origin/master and make sure the working copy is identical to that commit.

Comment: How do you know the branch originated from `master`?

Comment: I don't, that's why I wrote "... in this case it *sounds* like ..."

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your branch has been created from `master` in a situation like below :

```
A---B---C <<< master
         \
          \
           D---E <<< your-branch
```

You can recreate your branch at whichever point you need with

```
# if your-branch is currently checked out, just
git reset --hard master

# or alternatively, if another branch is currently checked out
git checkout -B your-branch master
```

resulting in this situation

```
    A---B---C <<< master, your-branch
             \
              \
               D---E <<< candidates for garbage collection
```